# How to export an HTML table with rowspan/colspan to pdf using JSPDF-Autotable

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have an HTML table with rowspan/colspan.How can i export this table to pdf using JSPDF-Autotable/or any other export to pdf plugin?
I want to create a button which when clicked exports the entire table as a downloadable pdf with rowspan and colspan visible in the table created in pdf. 
My table is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable/master/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{

 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("my-table"));
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {startY: 40});
    doc.save("Report.pdf");
}

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <table border='1' id="my-table">
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan='2'>D</td>
<td colspan='2'>$100</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td >E</td>
<td >F</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `Id` for your table, wrap headers in `<thead>` and contents in `<tbody>`.

```
 <table id="my-table">
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then in JS use `autoTableHtmlToJson()` method to get JSON data from table.

```
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("my-table"));
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {startY: 40});
```

Comment: see my edited code...the table getting saved as pdf has difference in rowspan/colspan ...ie. the actual table is different from the pdf one